# Using url as a variable

Tags: php

I normally use a GET variable i n the URL to determined what data to show in my template.

Today I am not passing a variable. I am including a file named inludes/leftmenu.php on every page but depending on the page name I want to show different data.

leftmenu.php looks like so:

```
$page = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$page_name = get_page_name($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

   if ($page_name == "classes.php")
        {
<h2 class="left_h2">Class Schedules &amp; Info</h2>
<ul class="left_ul">
    <li>Immersion Programs</li>
    <li>Afternoon Programs</li>
    <li>Immersion Schedule</li>
    <li>Afternoon Schedule</li>
</ul>

    }else if($page_name == "about.php")
    {

<h2 class="left_h2">About Us</h2>
<ul class="left_ul">
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Photo Scrapbook</li>
</ul>
   }else if ($page_name == "news.php")
    {

<h2 class="left_h2">News &amp; Events</h2>
<ul class="left_ul">
    <li>News</li>
    <li>Events</li>
</ul>

  }
```

Comment: Sorry,I had two issues in my head while writing this post and I got them mixed up. But you actually both questions got answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a PHP array:

```
$pages = array(
  '/events.php' => 'includes/events_menu.php',
  '/news.php'   => 'includes/news_menu.php'
);

// lookup the appropriate include file
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$include = $pages[$uri];

// produce a default page if the URI wasn't recognised
if (!isset($include)) {
  $include = 'includes/default.php';
}

include($include);
```

Comment: Can $pages have multiple keys for each value. i.e. $pages = array('/events.php, /home_events.php, away_events.php ' => 'includes/events_menu.php');

Comment: no, you'd have to have duplicate keys all mapping individually to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's faster, but there are many ways to do this.

E.g. with an array:

```
$page_name = get_page_name($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$includes = array(
    'events.php' => 'includes/events_menu.php',
    'news.php' => 'includes/news_menu.php'
);

if(isset($includes[$page_name])) include($includes[$page_name]);
else die('this page does not exist');
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP [polulates $_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) with variables passed in the URL. Though I do not recommend having a user-passed variable as a function of what your code includes.

an array is a better method, ofcourse, but you may also look into [realpath()](http://php.net/realpath) and make sure it's in DOCUMENT_ROOT /includes

Comment: Sorry I asked my question incorrectly. Please see my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

You can create array with paths and then use `in_array` function, which will reduce `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a menu for every single page, you could go with

```
include('includes/'.basename($page_name, ".php").'_menu.php');
```

Comment: Ouch, I will not be taking this advise !

Comment: Robert, if ever you have a moment, could you please let me know why this is such bad advice (for personal knowledge and better understanding)? Thanks. 
I guess the solution doesn't really apply at all to the edited question, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REQUEST_URI`, but you have to keep in mind that it always starts with a `/` slash. Unless you apply `basename()` you therefore would have to write:

```
if ($page_name == "/events.php")
```

The `if` statements are a workable approach if you only need a few page names. Otherwise use an `switch` or an url->filename map (as an array).

If you are using a RewriteRule to map all incoming URLs to a single PHP script, you could also think about using `PATH_INFO` instead of `REQUEST_URI`.